# Is it safe in Python to use 'from copy import copy' statement?

Tags: python, python-import

Python has complicated namespaces and modules notion, so i unsure about this. Normally python `module` and something that is imported from it has different names or only module is imported and it's content used by fully qualified name:

```
import copy # will use copy.copy
from time import localtime # "localtime" has different name from "time".
```

But what if module has same name as something that i'm importing from it? For example:

```
from copy import copy
copy( "something" )
```

Is it safe? Maybe it's some complicated consequences that i can't see?

Comment: It is fine, although not recommended, but the reason it's not recommended is that you want to import modules, and almost never import a specific function or a class from the module.
Meaning you want to do `import copy` and then use `copy.copy` function.
It is recommended because you want to know from where each function and class comes from (a specific module or maybe the current program.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From PEP8 ( http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

When importing a class from a class-containing module, it's usually okay to spell this:

```
from myclass import MyClass
from foo.bar.yourclass import YourClass
```

If this spelling causes local name clashes, then spell them

```
import myclass
import foo.bar.yourclass
```

and use "myclass.MyClass" and "foo.bar.yourclass.YourClass".

Comment: Is it safe to write `from copy import copy` in Python?

Comment: It is perfectly safe. The `copy` module contains two functions (`copy` and `deepcopy`), and one exception (`error`). While it is perfectly fine (even from a pep8 perspective) to import them into your namespace either singularly: `from copy import copy` or more than one: `from copy import copy, deepcopy`.  With generic names (like copy) it can quickly become confusing to read your code and understand where a function is coming from, it is therefore often good practice to import the module name only (and not the functions etc. inside): `from xml.dom import minidom` then using `minidom.parse(..)`